# Diffie-Hellman Key exchange with four parties

Tags: java, cryptography, key-management

I'm trying to modify an example Diffie-Hellman key exchange between three parties.

Here is the Code.

```java
           
       // Alice uses Carol's public key
            Key ac = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(carolKpair.getPublic(), false);
        // Bob uses Alice's public key
            Key ba = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(aliceKpair.getPublic(), false);
        // Carol uses Bob's public key
            Key cb = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(bobKpair.getPublic(), false);
            
            Key sc = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(carolKpair.getPublic(), false);
            
        // Alice uses Carol's result from above
            aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(cb, true);
        // Bob uses Alice's result from above
            bobKeyAgree.doPhase(ac, true);
        // Carol uses Bob's result from above
            carolKeyAgree.doPhase(ba, true);
            saraKeyAgree.doPhase(sc,true);
            
        // Alice, Bob and Carol compute their secrets
            byte[] aliceSharedSecret = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Alice secret: " + toHexString(aliceSharedSecret));
            byte[] bobSharedSecret = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Bob secret: " + toHexString(bobSharedSecret));
            byte[] carolSharedSecret = carolKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Carol secret: " + toHexString(carolSharedSecret));
            
            byte[] saraSharedSecret = saraKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Sara secret: " + toHexString(saraSharedSecret));
        // Compare Alice and Bob
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(aliceSharedSecret, bobSharedSecret))
                throw new Exception("Alice and Bob differ");
            System.out.println("Alice and Bob are the same");
        // Compare Bob and Carol
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(bobSharedSecret, carolSharedSecret))
                throw new Exception("Bob and Carol differ");
            System.out.println("Bob and Carol are the same");
```

At the end of this, only 3 of the results match and the fourth one is different. What've I done wrong here?

Comment: Do follow the dicussion at [DH with more than two parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Operation_with_more_than_two_parties).

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk this helped me with getting my head around the topic enough to answer, although it doesn't quite explain some of the code posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I'm still no cryptographer, so I've learnt a lot doing this, thank you!

I've rewritten the logic, the entire example is posted below for anyone that stumbles across this later on. It's also been tested in the sandbox over at [Compile Java](https://www.compilejava.net)

I'll attempt to explain what's happening here, although if anyone reading this notices any gaping flaws in my implementation/explanation, please let me know. I can't say I entirely understand either it or the Java API used so I'd very much appreciate any clarification.

**Explanation**

This uses some clever maths, most of which is taken care of by the underlying APIs, we just need to tell it what to do, in the right order with the right values.

A generator *g* and modulus *p* are chosen and shared between all participants.

Alice, Bob, Carol and Sara choose private keys, (*A, B, C* and *S*) and compute their public keys (*g<sup>A</sup>, g<sup>B</sup>, g<sup>C</sup>, g<sup>S</sup>*). These are worked out from *g* raised to the power of their private keys, modulo *p*.

Each party needs to send the result of their operation to the next party along, and each party needs to perform *n-1* operations using a value passed from another party, where *n* is the number of parties.

At the end of this, every party will have raised *g* by the power of everyone else's private key modulo *p*, without ever revealing to each other what their private keys are, using a process and pass method.

On the first pass, each participant computes an intermediate value (*g<sup>AB</sup>, g<sup>BC</sup>* etc) by raising their public keys by the power of the public key of the participant to their left, modulo *p*.

On passes 2+, they repeat this process, but using the result of the previous operation from the person on their left, raising that result to the power of their own private key, modulo *p*.

This pass-and-compute process repeats until each person has computed g<sup>ABCS</sup>, which becomes the shared secret.

Due to the way maths works (The Law of Exponents if I'm not mistaken), 
*g<sup>ABCS</sup> =  g<sup>BCSA</sup> =  g<sup>CSAB</sup> = g<sup>SABC</sup>* etc

An evesdropper, Eve would be able to see the values of *g<sup>A</sup>, g<sup>B</sup>, g<sup>C</sup>, g<sup>S</sup>, g<sup>AB</sup>, g<sup>BC</sup>, g<sup>CS</sup>, g<sup>SA</sup>, g<sup>ABC</sup>, g<sup>BCS</sup>, g<sup>CSA</sup>*, but cannot use any combination of these to efficiently reproduce *g<sup>ABCS</sup>*, as they don't know the values of *A, B, C*  or *S*, as these are the private keys that are never transmitted.

This in theory could scale to more participants. By following the pattern in the code below. You'd add another participant, add them to the list of operations in each pass and add one more pass to ensure that everyone was doing the required number of operations.

I've added example code for four and five participants below.

**Example with four participants**

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.*;
   /*
    * This program executes the Diffie-Hellman key agreement protocol between
    * 4 parties: Alice, Bob, Carol and Sara using a shared 2048-bit DH parameter.
    */
    public class DHKeyAgreement4 {
        private DHKeyAgreement4() {}
        public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {


        // Alice creates her own DH key pair with 2048-bit key size
            KeyPairGenerator aliceKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            aliceKpairGen.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair aliceKpair = aliceKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // This DH parameters can also be constructed by creating a
        // DHParameterSpec object using agreed-upon values
            DHParameterSpec dhParamShared = ((DHPublicKey)aliceKpair.getPublic()).getParams();
        // Bob creates his own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator bobKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            bobKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair bobKpair = bobKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // Carol creates her own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator carolKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            carolKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair carolKpair = carolKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // Carol creates her own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator saraKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            saraKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair saraKpair = saraKpairGen.generateKeyPair();




          //Alice initialize
          KeyAgreement aliceKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Alice computes gA
          aliceKeyAgree.init(aliceKpair.getPrivate());

          //Bob initialize
          KeyAgreement bobKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Bob computes gB
          bobKeyAgree.init(bobKpair.getPrivate());

          //Carol initialize
          KeyAgreement carolKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Carol computes gC
          carolKeyAgree.init(carolKpair.getPrivate());

          //Sara initialize
          KeyAgreement saraKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Sara computes gS
          saraKeyAgree.init(saraKpair.getPrivate());


          //First Pass

          //Alice computes gSA
          Key gSA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(saraKpair.getPublic(), false);

          //Bob computes gAB
          Key gAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(aliceKpair.getPublic(), false); 

          //Carol computes gBC
          Key gBC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(bobKpair.getPublic(), false); 

          //Sara computes gCS
          Key gCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(carolKpair.getPublic(), false);


          //Second Pass

          //Alice computes gCSA
          Key gCSA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(gCS, false);

          //Bob computes gSAB
          Key gSAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(gSA, false);

          //Carol computes gABC
          Key gABC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(gAB, false);

          //Sara computes gBCS
          Key gBCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(gBC, false); 


          //Third Pass

          //Alice computes gBCSA
          Key gBCSA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(gBCS, true); //This is Alice's secret

          //Bob computes gCSAB
          Key gCSAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(gCSA, true); //This is Bob's secret

          //Sara Computes gABCS
          Key gABCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(gABC, true); //This is Sara's secret

          //Carol computes gSABC
          Key gSABC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(gSAB, true); //This is Carol's secret



        // Alice, Bob, Carol and Sara compute their secrets
            byte[] aliceSharedSecret = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Alice secret: " + toHexString(aliceSharedSecret));

            byte[] bobSharedSecret = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Bob secret: " + toHexString(bobSharedSecret));

            byte[] carolSharedSecret = carolKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Carol secret: " + toHexString(carolSharedSecret));

            byte[] saraSharedSecret = saraKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Sara secret: " + toHexString(saraSharedSecret));

        // Compare Alice and Bob
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(aliceSharedSecret, bobSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Alice and Bob differ");//    throw new Exception("Alice and Bob differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Alice and Bob are the same");
        // Compare Bob and Carol
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(bobSharedSecret, carolSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Bob and Carol differ");//throw new Exception("Bob and Carol differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Bob and Carol are the same");
          //Compare Carol and Sara
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(carolSharedSecret, saraSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Carol and Sara differ");//throw new Exception("Carol and Sara differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Carol and Sara are the same");

        }
    /*
     * Converts a byte to hex digit and writes to the supplied buffer
     */
        private static void byte2hex(byte b, StringBuffer buf) {
            char[] hexChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                                '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
            int high = ((b & 0xf0) >> 4);
            int low = (b & 0x0f);
            buf.append(hexChars[high]);
            buf.append(hexChars[low]);
        }
    /*
     * Converts a byte array to hex string
     */
        private static String toHexString(byte[] block) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            int len = block.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                byte2hex(block[i], buf);
                if (i < len-1) {
                    buf.append(":");
                }
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    }
```

**Example with five participants**

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.*;
   /*
    * This program executes the Diffie-Hellman key agreement protocol between
    * 5 parties: Alice, Bob, Carol, Sara and Dave using a shared 2048-bit DH parameter.
    */
    public class DHKeyAgreement5 {
        private DHKeyAgreement5() {}
        public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {


        // Alice creates her own DH key pair with 2048-bit key size
            KeyPairGenerator aliceKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            aliceKpairGen.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair aliceKpair = aliceKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // This DH parameters can also be constructed by creating a
        // DHParameterSpec object using agreed-upon values
            DHParameterSpec dhParamShared = ((DHPublicKey)aliceKpair.getPublic()).getParams();
        // Bob creates his own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator bobKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            bobKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair bobKpair = bobKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // Carol creates her own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator carolKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            carolKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair carolKpair = carolKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
        // Sara creates her own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator saraKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            saraKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair saraKpair = saraKpairGen.generateKeyPair();
                    // Dave creates her own DH key pair using the same params
            KeyPairGenerator daveKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            daveKpairGen.initialize(dhParamShared);
            KeyPair daveKpair = daveKpairGen.generateKeyPair();



          //Alice initialize
          KeyAgreement aliceKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Alice computes gA
          aliceKeyAgree.init(aliceKpair.getPrivate());

          //Bob initialize
          KeyAgreement bobKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Bob computes gB
          bobKeyAgree.init(bobKpair.getPrivate());

          //Carol initialize
          KeyAgreement carolKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Carol computes gC
          carolKeyAgree.init(carolKpair.getPrivate());

          //Sara initialize
          KeyAgreement saraKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Sara computes gS
          saraKeyAgree.init(saraKpair.getPrivate());

          //Dave initialize
          KeyAgreement daveKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
          //Sara computes gS
          daveKeyAgree.init(daveKpair.getPrivate());


          //First Pass

          //Alice computes gDA
          Key gDA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(daveKpair.getPublic(), false);

          //Bob computes gAB
          Key gAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(aliceKpair.getPublic(), false); 

          //Carol computes gBC
          Key gBC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(bobKpair.getPublic(), false); 

          //Sara computes gCS
          Key gCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(carolKpair.getPublic(), false);

          //Dave computed gSD
          Key gSD = daveKeyAgree.doPhase(saraKpair.getPublic(), false);


          //Second Pass

          //Alice computes gSDA
          Key gSDA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(gSD, false);

          //Bob computes gDAB
          Key gDAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(gDA, false);

          //Carol computes gABC
          Key gABC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(gAB, false);

          //Sara computes gBCS
          Key gBCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(gBC, false); 

          //Dave computes gCSD
          Key gCSD = daveKeyAgree.doPhase(gCS, false); 

          //Third Pass

          //Alice computes gCSDA
          Key gCSDA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(gCSD, false); 

          //Bob computes gSDAB
          Key gSDAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(gSDA, false); 

          //Carol computes gDABC
          Key gDABC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(gDAB, false); 

          //Sara Computes gABCS
          Key gABCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(gABC, false); 

          //Dave computes gBCSC
          Key gBCSD = daveKeyAgree.doPhase(gBCS, false); 

          //Fourth Pass

          //Alice computes gBCSDA
          Key gBCSDA = aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(gBCSD, true); //This is Alice's secret

          //Bob computes gSDABC
          Key gCSDAB = bobKeyAgree.doPhase(gCSDA, true); //This is Bob's secret

          //Carol computes gSABC
          Key gSDABC = carolKeyAgree.doPhase(gSDAB, true); //This is Carol's secret

          //Sara Computes gABCS
          Key gDABCS = saraKeyAgree.doPhase(gDABC, true); //This is Sara's secret


          Key gABCSD = daveKeyAgree.doPhase(gABCS, true); //This is Dave's secret



        // Alice, Bob, Carol and Sara compute their secrets
            byte[] aliceSharedSecret = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Alice secret: " + toHexString(aliceSharedSecret));

            byte[] bobSharedSecret = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Bob secret: " + toHexString(bobSharedSecret));

            byte[] carolSharedSecret = carolKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Carol secret: " + toHexString(carolSharedSecret));

            byte[] saraSharedSecret = saraKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Sara secret: " + toHexString(saraSharedSecret));

          byte[] daveSharedSecret = daveKeyAgree.generateSecret();
            System.out.println("Dave secret: " + toHexString(daveSharedSecret));

        // Compare Alice and Bob
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(aliceSharedSecret, bobSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Alice and Bob differ");//    throw new Exception("Alice and Bob differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Alice and Bob are the same");
        // Compare Bob and Carol
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(bobSharedSecret, carolSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Bob and Carol differ");//throw new Exception("Bob and Carol differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Bob and Carol are the same");
          //Compare Carol and Sara
            if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(carolSharedSecret, saraSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Carol and Sara differ");//throw new Exception("Carol and Sara differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Carol and Sara are the same");
          //Compare Sara and Dave
          if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(saraSharedSecret, daveSharedSecret))
                System.out.println("Sara and Dave differ");//throw new Exception("Carol and Sara differ");
            else
                System.out.println("Sara and Dave are the same");

        }
    /*
     * Converts a byte to hex digit and writes to the supplied buffer
     */
        private static void byte2hex(byte b, StringBuffer buf) {
            char[] hexChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                                '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
            int high = ((b & 0xf0) >> 4);
            int low = (b & 0x0f);
            buf.append(hexChars[high]);
            buf.append(hexChars[low]);
        }
    /*
     * Converts a byte array to hex string
     */
        private static String toHexString(byte[] block) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            int len = block.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                byte2hex(block[i], buf);
                if (i < len-1) {
                    buf.append(":");
                }
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: by using your logic Alice, bob and carol keys were different  from each other and i need all four have same keys

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the example you worked from as a separate block?

Comment: Alice computes A=ga, Bob computes B=gb and Charlie computes C=gc

.

A,B
and C

are published.

Alice computes AC=Ca
and AB=Ba and Bob computes BC=Cb

.

AB,AC
and BC

are published.

Alice computes ABC=BCa
, Bob computes ABC=ACb and Charlie computes ABC=ABc

.

Everybody shares ABC=gabc
 This is the Algorithm for three parties and which implemented in code above

Comment: No, I mean can you edit your question to include the actual code you used as a basis, or provide a link.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html?fbclid=IwAR3Fc61ITOr2ICs6oL5JUgiM7GTXWv57fzRNkAT1i4Ro1yIv5jclOPy1pig#DH2Ex 
From here i used Deffie Helman Key exchange with Three parties

Comment: Smashing. If that's worked, please accept the answer :)